# Why use webelement.click() in Selenium if send_keys(Keys.SPACE) and send_keys(Keys.RETURN) accomplishes the same thing?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation

I noticed that the click() method in selenium will fail in most sites that have a more complex design, like the not clickable at point (x,y) exception, but by just highlighting the element and sending return I haven't seen an error since.

I have been trying to go through each posts of a few websites, and noticed that the click method would only work 100% on the websites that had a simple design, but would fail almost 100% of the time when it tried to click a post from a weblement list in more complex designs, my question is why would one prefer to use click instead of the other way.

Comment: Update the question with an instance (relevant text based HTML and code trils and error) where `webelement.click()` fails

Answer (score 0):

Symply: No.

- The `Keys.SPACE` dispatches a space (`" "`), which can trigger a button, but doesn't need to.
- `Keys.ENTER` on the other hand sends a new-line (enter, `\n`) key, which is often used instead of clicking on a element.

Answer (score 0):

### `click()`

[`click()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click()) method clicks an element. There are some preconditions for an element to be clicked. The element must be ***visible*** and it must have a *`height`* and *`width`* greater than ***0***.

---

### Enum Keys

The [Enum Keys](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html) are the representations of pressable keys that aren't text. These are stored in the Unicode PUA [(Private Use Area)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) code points, 0xE000-0xF8FF. As an example:

- [`Keys.ENTER`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html#ENTER)
- [`Keys.RETURN`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html#RETURN)
- [`Keys.SPACE`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html#SPACE)

---

### This usecase

From the above two details it can be draw a conclusion the click method and the ENUM keys are used for different objectives/actions. But as per your observations why all the three behaves similarly can be known digging deeper into their implementation and tests.